# How do I upload a file when I know the client's filepath?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, swfupload

I'm interested in the way [Sonic Living](http://www.sonicliving.com) detects your iTunes library XML file. It prompts the user to approve its actions, then automatically uploads the XML file based on the client OS (and assuming the default installation path of iTunes).

How the heck does it do that? None of the upload libraries I've looked at have this feature. They all assume that a user will click "Select file..." then browse around for the right thing to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses Java. See this tutorial for how to read local files (with authorisation).

> Now we need to make an (inofficial) certificate. It IS a certificate, but the browser-plugin will display a certificate-requester, which says that it is unofficial. We do not need to care about this - the user has to decide if he trusts you or not.

http://www.captain.at/programming/java/

Comment: Thanks, Simon! I got thrown off by the Prototype library being used and assumed a JavaScript implementation.